# knockout js dropdown list with an option to enter new value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to implement a dropdown list with adding new item option using knock out js. That is user can select an option from the dropdown list and he can enter new value from the same dropdown list. Can anybody have an idea of how this can be achieved using knockout js?

```
<select>
    <option>Enter new option</option>
    <option>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
    <option>Item3</option>
    <option>Item4</option>
</select>
```

As shown in the above dropdown list when user selects enter new option item from dropdown list he can able to enter the text.

Thanks,

Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement a 'ComboBox' just using a `select` in HTML.  You would have to do a work-around to implement this.  Something like this could be a start:

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown" data-bind="options: dropDownItems, value: dropDownValue">
</select>
<input id="textbox" type="text" data-bind="visible: textBoxVisible" />
<button data-bind="click: showTextBoxValue">Show Current Value</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Demo(){
   var self = this;
   self.dropDownItems = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Enter new option'];
   self.dropDownValue = ko.observable('one');
   self.textBoxVisible = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.dropDownValue() === 'Enter new option';
   });
   self.showTextBoxValue = function(){
      alert(self.chosenValue());
   };
   return self;         
}       

ko.applyBindings(new Demo());
```

See here for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K2sU4/